# How to pass parameter via hyperlink to embedded google maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, hyperlink

I have a problem with google maps. I need to pass some parameters (address and some marker option) to an embedded google map via hyperlink. Is it possible?

Do you have any suggestion?

Regards,

Marcello

Comment: Yes, it's possible. You probably need to clarify exactly what you're trying to do but there's no reason why you couldn't append query strings to your url, pull those out when the document loads, then construct a query to the Google Maps API

Comment: http://moz.com/ugc/everything-you-never-wanted-to-know-about-google-maps-parameters

Answer (score 0):

Yes ! It's easy. Let me give you an example:

This snippet creates a static map V2 by getting your current position and draws another marker in a 1km radius and draws a line between them. You can easily see how it works.

```
<script>
function showMap(position) {
var lat = Math.random()*((position.coords.latitude+0.005)-(position.coords.latitude -0.005))+(position.coords.latitude - 0.005);
var log = Math.random()*((position.coords.longitude+0.01)-(position.coords.longitude -0.01))+(position.coords.longitude - 0.01);

$('#map').css({'background-image':'url(http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center='+position.coords.latitude+','+position.coords.longitude+'&zoom=15&size=600x305&maptype=roadmap &markers=color:red%7C'+position.coords.latitude+','+position.coords.longitude+'%7C'+lat+','+log+'&path=color:0x17A689|weight:2|'+position.coords.latitude+','+position.coords.longitude+'|'+lat+','+log+'&sensor=false)','background-position':'right','background-repeat':'no-repeat'});
}

navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showMap);
</script>
```

When the script loads it will change the `<div id="map"></div>` and assign it a background image with the dimension specified in the link.

You can make a function that gets arguments and use them to make the map.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/